# Barcode decoding with pyzbar on raspberry pi

Tags: picamera

I am using pyzbar to decode barcodes on Raspberry Pi 3 using Pi Camera v1 (resolution 1296x972). Qr codes are decoded very well. When decoding two dimensional barcodes (CODABAR), the success rate is very low.

I have tried saving one frame from the video stream and decode it with pyzbar on the Raspberry and it fails. When i try to decode the same image on Ubuntu, and decodes it successfully.

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('sampleImage.png')
d = pyzbar.decode(img)

print (d)
```

Any thoughts what may be the problem?

The following image is my specific use case. 
[image: eBarcode image]
Because I am using Pi Camera v1 to take images, I tried to do adjustment to image sharpness:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
self.camera = PiCamera()
self.camera.sharpness = 100
```

The following image is with sharpness 100. However, `pyzbar` still fails to decode it on the Raspberry Pi.

[image]

I have done thresholding with cv2 (threshold value 50). It still fails to decode on the Raspberry Pi. The resulting image is the following:
[image]

Comment: looks like you may be using poor quality barcodes .... find a barcode that has better defined spaces between the bars

Comment: Yes, the barcodes are with poor quality, but it still successfully decodes on Ubuntu. I wonder if the problem is because of the processing power of the Raspberry, or processing timeout...

Comment: print a good quality barcode for testing .... there is a lot of online web pages where you can generate a barcode in the PNG format ... i think that your barcode is codabar  .... when you get good barcode reads, then start to introduce less than optimal quality barcodes

Comment: Thank you for the answer @jsotola. I have generated the codabar online and it decodes. I will start adding artifacts to reduce its quality and see where exactly it starts failing. I have edited the question and added thresholded image example.